# Search for specific files in folder without subfolders using perl

Tags: file, perl, find, subdirectory

i want to search for specific file inside a Folder but not in the subfolder of this folder. Following Structure is given:

```
FolderA
|
|__SubFolder1
    |__File1.txt
    |__File2.txt
|
|__File3.txt
|__File4.cmd
|__File5.txt
```

Now i am searching all txt files in Folder A like this:

```
sub GetFiles()
{
  my @DIRS = (FolderA);
  find ( \&searchFiles, @DIRS );
  for my $myfile (%MYFILES) {
    ####do something with the files###
  }
}

sub searchFiles() 
{
  return unless /\.txt/;
  return unless -f $File::Find::name;

  $MYFILES{$File::Find::name} = {'NAME'=> $File::Find::name }
}
```

The Code looks good to me but I always get all .txt Files, even those from Subfolder.
Actual result is like this:

File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
File5.txt

But I want only

File3.txt
File5.txt

Where did I the mistake?

Comment: `glob("${dir}/*.txt")` will return filenames for all `*.txt` files in `$dir` directory.

Comment: Polar Bear's code suffers from a [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bug. You should actually use `glob("\Q$dir\E/*.txt")`

Comment: @ikegami -- if variable `${dir}` was previously sanitized then it should be safe to use in glob.

Comment: @Polar Bear, No, `glob("${dir}/*.txt")` fails for perfectly legitimate inputs (such as a `$dir = "My Files"`). Validation won't help. (Don't you hate when use a service that won't accept cyrillc letters? That's what happens someone follows your advice.)

Comment: @ikegami -- I like your critique, this is how I learn something new!

Comment: @ikegami -- I do not hate anything, I accept sometimes as nonsense as for example with NA Windows not accepting Cyrillic as command line arguments. You showed a way around of it -- and I accept it as a solution to limitation of the system design. Same I could say about BIOS when it had DOS inherited limitations.

Comment: Well, I would hate it if an airline (for example) couldn't accept my name or called me by something that wasn't my name. It's a lot of fun when your boarding pass doesn't match your passport ...not. Same goes for the computer tools I use. I don't want them crapping out because my file names aren't to its liking. Doesn't matter if you call it limitation or bug.

Comment: @ikegami -- I order air tickets and print boarding pass at home myself and see the problem right away. By the way I never had any problem of this kind!!! Why you see everywhere possibility of exploit is beyond of my understanding -- it should be driving you _nuts_ ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use File::Find.

```
use File::Find qw( find );

my @dir_qfns = qw( FolderA );

find(
   sub {
      # Don't do anything for a base dir.
      return if $_ eq '.';

      # Don't recurse.
      $File::Find::prune = 1;

      stat($_) 
         or do {
            warn("Skipping \"$_\": Can't stat: $!\n");
            next;
         };

      -f _
         or return;
      /\.txt\z/
         or return;

      # ... do something with $File::Find::name/$_ ...
   },
   @dir_qfns,
);
```

It's far simpler with File::Find::Rule. (Isn't it always?)

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my @dir_qfns = qw( FolderA );

for my $qfn (
   File::Find::Rule
   ->mindepth(1)
   ->maxdepth(1)
   ->file
   ->name("*.txt")
   ->in(@dir_qfns)
) {
   # ... do something with $qfn ...
}
```

You could also do it using `glob`.

```
my @dir_qfns = qw( FolderA );

for my $dir_qfn (@dir_qfns) {
   for my $fn (glob("\Q$dir_qfn\E/*.txt")) {
      my $qfn = "$dir_qfn/$fn";
      stat($qfn) 
         or do {
            warn("Skipping \"$qfn\": Can't stat: $!\n");
            next;
         };

      -f _
         or next;

      # ... do something with $fn/$qfn ...
   }
}
```

(Note that using `quotemeta` (e.g. via `\Q..\E` as shown above) is not a proper way of generating a glob pattern from a directory name on Windows.)

Comment: The part with use File::Find qw( find ); not working for me :(
I just copied the whole code and change some paths, thts all, but no files found...

Comment: @digestBen oh, I forgot to take into account that the callback sub is called for the starting dir. It gets pruned, so `find` doesn't go any further. This just reinforces my point that F::F isn't the tool for this. I'll fix it later; I'm not at my computer right now.

Comment: Fixed. It's really unfortunate that `find` doesn't provide the depth of the path for which the callback is called.

Answer (score -1):

Get list of all `.dll` files in `c:\Program Files\Windows Defender` directory

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dir_defend = 'c:\Program Files\Windows Defender';
my $files_dll  = getFileList($dir_defend,'dll');

say '
  File list
-------------------------';
say for @{ $files_dll };

sub getFileList {
    my $dir = shift;
    my $ext = shift;

    opendir my $dh, $dir
        or die "Can't opendir $dir";

    my @files = grep { /\.${ext}$/ && -f "$dir/$_" } readdir($dh);

    close $dh;

    return \@files;
}
```

Output

```
  File list
-------------------------
AMMonitoringProvider.dll
DefenderCSP.dll
EppManifest.dll
MpAsDesc.dll
MpAzSubmit.dll
MpClient.dll
MpCommu.dll
MpEvMsg.dll
MpOAV.dll
MpProvider.dll
MpRtp.dll
MpSvc.dll
MsMpCom.dll
MsMpLics.dll
MsMpRes.dll
ProtectionManagement.dll
shellext.dll
```

Comment: Code injection bug. `/\.${ext}$/` should be `/\.\Q$ext\E$/`. Actually, there's a second bug. It should be `/\.\Q$ext\E\z/` unless you really do want to accept a file named `foo.dll<LF>`. Also note that this silently skips files it can't `stat`. The solution is found in the earlier answer.

Comment: @ikegami -- if you have `foo.dll<LF>` files then I would suggest you to reinstall OS. It definitely you computer was exploited and you should not trust that other files was not affected - :). Reinstall system and restore your data from backup :)

Comment: You're making my point for me. If they're so bad, then why did you write code that accepts them?  I see the bugs are still in your answer.

Comment: @ikegami -- on my systems I do not have **weird files** and in my case everything works without any problem. In your case [readdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) documentation should be re-written as it also gives a sample of the code which in your opinion is 'No, no, no, no --- this code advertise possible exploit'.

Comment: First of all, it doesn't matter what's on your system. Why do you think it does?! /// Secondly, the argument that buggy code is ok if the bug isn't currently being exercised makes no sense for so many reasons, given that there is no cost to doing it right/fixing the bugs. /// Finally, what exploit are you talking about? I don't know of any exploits in `readdir` (or in your code). I'm not sure what that has to do with me either; **I'm just saying your code doesn't do what the OP wants**, and that you should fix it. I showed you how.

Comment: @ikegami -- taken directly from [readdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) `my @dots = grep { /^\./ && -f "$some_dir/$_" } readdir($dh);` according to you it should be written as `my @dots = grep { /^\./ && -f "\Q$some_dir\E/$_" } readdir($dh);`.

Comment: Re "*according to you it should be written as `my @dots = grep { /^\./ && -f "\Q$some_dir\E/$_" } readdir($dh);`*" I never said anything of the kind!!!! That wouldn't work, and the code in the docs is correct. Read my first comment again. It's your regular expression that's wrong.

Comment: @ikegami -- is this not yours `glob("\Q$dir\E/*.txt")`? If I assign `$ext = 'dll'` why I would need `/\.\Q$ext\E\z/`?

Comment: Re "*is this not yours `glob("\Q$dir\E/*.txt")`*"? Yes, but `-f "$some_dir/$_"` isn't. `-f` takes a path, `glob` doesn't. You need to convert the path into a glob pattern that generates the path.

Comment: Re "*If I assign `$ext = 'dll'`*",  But you didn't. You assigned the first argument. By not using `/\.dll\z/`, you acknowledge that `$ext` is variable, and so you're own code contradicts your arguments. You know damn well that `$ext` is variable --that's why we call them variables-- and not some constant.

Comment: Even if you had done `$ext = 'dll'`, who would believe that the value of `$ext` is a regex pattern instead of a extension? You'd still have a bug, either an injection bug or a lack of documentation bug.